# npm install opencv4nodejs error on mac m1 bigSur

Tags: node.js, macos, opencv

I have been trying to install opencv4nodejs package with `npm install opencv4nodejs` command. But unfortunately the below is being thrown. Have done some research and done few tweaks, but all those doesn't worked.

Below is the error:

```
manikanthvanka@Manikanths-MacBook-Pro react-file-upload-master % npm install opencv4nodejs
> opencv-build@0.1.9 install /Users/manikanthvanka/Downloads/react- 
file-upload-master/node_modules/opencv-build
> node ./install.js
info install OPENCV4NODEJS_DISABLE_AUTOBUILD is set
info install skipping auto build...

> opencv4nodejs@5.6.0 install /Users/manikanthvanka/Downloads/react- 
file-upload-master/node_modules/opencv4nodejs
> node ./install/install.js

info install OPENCV_LIB_DIR is not set, looking for default lib dir
info install using lib dir: /usr/local/lib
/Users/manikanthvanka/Downloads/react-file-upload- 
master/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/install/install.js:45
throw new Error('no OpenCV libraries found in lib dir: ' + libDir)
 ^

 Error: no OpenCV libraries found in lib dir: /usr/local/lib
 at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/manikanthvanka/Downloads/react-file- 
 upload-master/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/install/install.js:45:9)
 at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
 at Object.Module._extensions..js 
 (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
 at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
 at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
 at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] 
 (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
  at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
  npm WARN @tinymce/tinymce-react@3.10.2 requires a peer of 
  react@^17.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer 
  dependencies yourself.
  npm WARN @tinymce/tinymce-react@3.10.2 requires a peer of react- 
  dom@^17.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer 
  dependencies yourself.
  npm WARN bootstrap@4.6.0 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but 
  none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
  npm WARN bootstrap@4.6.0 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.16.1 but n. 
  one is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
  npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 
  3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 
  3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none 
  is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! errno 1
   npm ERR! opencv4nodejs@5.6.0 install: `node ./install/install.js`
   npm ERR! Exit status 1
   npm ERR! 
   npm ERR! Failed at the opencv4nodejs@5.6.0 install script.
   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
   additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /Users/manikanthvanka/.npm/_logs/2021-03- 
    07T11_03_42_873Z-debug.log
    manikanthvanka@Manikanths-MacBook-Pro react-file-upload-master %
```

Answer (score 2):

Step 1 : Find the opencv lib location on your mac using this below command

```
find / -name "OpenCVConfig.cmake"
```

Step 2 : Gives you the below path

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib
```

Step 3 : Open zshrc file

```
open ~/.zshrc
```

Step 4 : Place the below line in zshrc file

```
export OPENCV_LIB_DIR="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_4/lib"
```

Step 5 : Save & Close the zshrc file
Step 6 : Execute below command

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Step 7 : Now try to do npm i opencv4nodejs

Cheers!

Comment: Finally, one that works! Thanks!

Comment: step 4 save my life, may thanks

Answer (score 1):

try do this

`$ export OPENCV4NODEJS_DISABLE_AUTOBUILD=1`

`$ npm i opencv4nodejs`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I was able to get the full installation of opencv4nodejs working. I needed to downgrade node from version 16 to version 14 and do a little bit of compiler option digging!

**Current Setup**

***macOS Big Sur*** v11.6.1 
***Homebrew*** 3.3.2 
***opencv*** 4.5.3_2 
***node*** v14.18.1

**Node installation** (with Homebrew) 
brew install node@14

**opencv installation** (with Homebrew) 
brew install opencv

**opencv4nodejs installtion** (with node installer)

- Before installing set both the following compiler flags

  export CXXFLAGS="-std=c++14 -Wno-c++11-narrowing"
- In the same terminal where you have set the above environment variables run the installation

  npm install opencv4nodejs

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I did solve the issue with the following steps.

First all of. I checked the npm version, for this case I recommend you updated or pass your software resources at the next version.

[NodeJs 14.16.0](https://nodejs.org/es/download/releases/)

**NodeJs version: 14.16.0.** You can verify the version with this command if you had another NodeJs version installed

```
node --version
```

**Npm version: 6.4.11** You need verify if you had this version installed only you will able to validate this if you have NodeJs but if you didn't have node you can install the version I recommend you

```
npm --version
```

After you set the NodeJs and npm versions you need to verify the following things

- Have visual studio 2015 or latest with the development for desktop component
- Have cmake program installed
- Have git bash
- Have Java or the language you will to work
- Have the environment variables for the above programs I mentioned

**OpenCv installation**

Then you can try again to install open Cv

You need to reopen another or new terminal and then you will execute this command

```
npm install --save opencv4nodejs
```

And then

```
npm install -g opencv4nodejs
```

After than or before don't forget to install appium I recommend you 1.19.1 version

You can verify if you have appium with opencv with open Cv doctor you can run `appium-doctor` and check if the Open cv component are present.

For to install appium doctor you can run this command, `npm install -g appium-doctor`

I hope this answers will be helpful for you

Autor: Eder Carbonero

Comment: missing 'V' in `npm install --save opencv4nodejs`. Same for the line below.

Answer (score 0):

I had to installed cmake, node-gyp and opencv-build to be able to install opencv4nodejs

```
brew install cmake
npm i -g node-gyp 
npm i -g opencv-build 
npm i -g @u4/opencv4nodejs
brew link --force opencv@4
```

the final command is not necessary required.